# Why doesn't my code compile and ask for a return statement?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why doesn't this code compile?

```java
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static Pair < Integer, Integer > swap(Pair < Integer, Integer > swapValues) {
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int a; //lets say a=2
        int b; //and b=3
        a= scanner.nextInt();
        b= scanner.nextInt();
        Pair pr =new Pair 
        int swap=a; //swap =a i.e swap is now 2
        a=b; //a was 0 now its 3 
        b=swap; //b was 0 now its 2
        //swap complete now a=3,b=2
    }
}
```

error:

```
Compilation Failed
./Solution.java:17: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
```

What does the compiler want from me?

Comment: Exactly as the error states... The method indicates that it should `return` a `Pair<Integer, Integer>` but it doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: First thing is, why to use Pair class. It represents a key value pair and not two values. Instead, create your own class with two attributes. Then you can pass instance of that class as parameter to this function and can return the same object with swapped values.

Comment: can u comment the fix bcoz i am not getting

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao it is given in question can't be changed has to be this way

Comment: and plz ignore that "Pair pr=new Pair"

Comment: So, the swap function signature is already provided?

Answer (score -1):

When creating methods you should (I think) always know if you want this method to return something or not. In this occasion, if I am right, you haven't mentioned what your return type is. Is it void? Is it an object? Is it an int e.t.c.The aforementioned solution returns the Pair class object that you assigned as or. If this is your desired return, then you may be OK.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The return type of the method is declared in the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).